# table showing from database in web page using JSON PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

Assuming a number of database tables exist on your MySQL server, the html web page must provide the user with the means to choose a single database table and subsequently display this as a table on the same web page without refreshing the whole web page. A drop-down list box is to be used to present the list of available database tables to the user. The drop-down list box contents must reflect the database tables presently available on the MySQL server without further web development amendments i.e. available database table names must not be hardcoded into the web page. This information must be obtained when the document has been loaded and must be returned as JSON.

Please guide me

Comment: start by formulating a plan the rest is easy

Comment: please bro guide me how

Comment: first get a pen and paper

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The user must be provided with the means to:
• view a table (including field headings) from the database, once a table has been selected;

• append new data to the selected database table. This will require form input fields and php script logic to insert the new detail into the relevant database table.

• search the currently selected database table for a specific field’s content so that only those records satisfying the selection are displayed in the table.

This involves additional input fields and logic to allow the user to select the field and field content.

Comment: i want to this please guide me

Comment: Please show us your attempts so far

Comment: i have start my project yet now ....

Answer (score 0):

You  can create an api in your server to getList all the database table name. Which will fill up your drop down in the UI.

Create another api which will take tableName/tableId as a parameter. Then get the data from that table. Rest you'll have to figure out.